# How to add retry delay in retry policy?

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to upload file using S3 API to Azure by using AWS SDK but I am facing intermittent file upload issue and this the error

`Cannot retry after server error, command is not replayable: [method=org.jclouds.azureblob.AzureBlobClient.public abstract java.lang.String org.jclouds.azureblob.AzureBlobClient.putBlob(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.azureblob.domain.AzureBlob)`

I have a retry policy in place as well

```
RetryPolicy.builder().numRetries(retries).build()
```

which retries for 10 times and gives and error was thing of adding a delay between the retries

Any idea how can i achive it , new to AWS ?

Comment: What does this have to do with AWS? This is **entirely** about azure. *"using S3 API to Azure"* - what?

Comment: Using an S3proxy for connecting to Azure https://github.com/gaul/s3proxy

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a backoff strategy: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/retry/RetryPolicy.BackoffStrategy.html

You can choose which one and set like this:

```
RetryPolicy.builder()
        .withBackoffStrategy(new ExponentialBackoffStrategy(100, 2000))
        .build()
```

Of course this is using AWS and Azure must have similar strategies.

[updated]

With Azure Java SDK, you can have the retry as:

```
RetryPolicy policy = new RetryExponentialRetry(BACKOFF_DELTA, MAX_RETRIES)
```